# Combine object and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a function that takes an array of objects, and an unlimited number of arrays, and combines them to form a single object. The inputs would follow this pattern:

```
let x = [{ name: 'Tom' }, { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Harry' }];
let y = [[1, 2, 3], 'id'];
let z = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'value'];

combine(x, y, z);
```

With the second element of `y` and `z` acting as the object key. Using these arguments, the function should return the following array:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    id: 1,
    value: 'a'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    id: 2,
    value: 'b'
  },
  {
    name: 'Harry',
    id: 3,
    value: 'c'
  },
]
```

The index of the current object should be used to get the correct element in the array. I have made an attempt at the problem:

```
function combine(object, ...arrays) {
  return object.map((obj, index) => {
    let items = arrays.map(arr => ({ 
      [arr[1]]: arr[0][index] 
    }));

    return Object.assign({}, obj, { items });
  });
}
```

This almost does the job, but results in the array items being hidden inside a nested `items` array, How can I solve this?

Comment: Use `map` check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8rL3sdrm/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had been assigning an object of object, and the result was a new object with the element items inside (another feature of object literal).

This approach use reduce instead of map and direct assign instead of object literal.

```
function combine(object, ...arrays) {
  return object.map((obj, index) => {
    const items = arrays.reduce((acc, arr) => { 
      acc[arr[1]] = arr[0][index] ;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    return Object.assign({}, obj, items);
  });
}

const x = [{ name: 'Tom' }, { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Harry' }];
const y = [[1, 2, 3], 'id'];
const z = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'value'];

combine(x, y, z);
```

You can also use the spread operator in the Object.assign, like this:

```
function combine(object, ...arrays) {
  return object.map((obj, index) => {
    let items = arrays.map(arr => ({ 
      [arr[1]]: arr[0][index] 
    }));

    return Object.assign({}, obj, ...items);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This almost does the job, but results in the array items being hidden inside a nested items array

The problem is that `items` is an array, whereas you only need the current item inside of that particular `map` callback. No need to nest loops here.

Also I would recommend avoiding multiple properties per `combine` call. The resulting code would look like this:

```
function combine(objects, [values, key]) {
    return objects.map((o, i) =>
        Object.assign({[key]: values[i]}, o)
    );
}
combine(combine(x, y), z);
```

If you then have multiple extensions to do, you can also use

```
[y, z].reduce(combine, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

With map and computed keys, you can achieve this.
Here's a working example:

```
let x = [{
    name: 'Tom'
}, {
    name: 'John'
}, {
    name: 'Harry'
}];
let y = [[1, 2, 3], 'id'];
let z = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'value'];

let result = [];

x.map(function (el, index) {
  result.push(el);
  let index = result.length -1;

  result[index][y[1]] = y[0][index];
  result[index][z[1]] = z[0][index];
});

console.log(result);
```